# Tradingview Higher timeframe RSI Indicator on lower timeframe current value

Tags: indicator, tradingview-api

I am trying to plot a 60min RSI on a 5min timeframe. However no matter how much I play around with it I cannot seem to figure out how to keep the current fluctuating value on screen. when I add the indicator the current value will show for a couple seconds and then it will disappear and resort to showing only the last closed value. I understand this is a repainting indicator, that is what I want but for some reason it will not stay on screen. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, Ive tried googling and playing around with the source code on pine editor but I have gone only in circles and got nowhere. please if you could help me with this. I feel it should be something simple I am missing.

I added 2 images to hopefully give a better understanding of what I am trying to accomplish.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I have calculated the RSI that can be plotted live in lower timeframe

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © seriousCockato20483

//@version=5
indicator("My script",overlay=false)
tf=input.timeframe("60","RSI Live Higher TF By Rohit")
period=input.int(14)
[bi,cls,rsiperiod]=request.security(syminfo.tickerid,tf,[bar_index,close,ta.rsi(close,period)])
var clst=cls
var clsb=cls
var u=0.0
var d=0.0
var urma=0.0
var drma=0.0
if bi>bi[1]
    clst:=cls
    u:= math.max(cls - clsb, 0) // upward ta.change
    d:= math.max(clsb - cls, 0) // downward ta.change
    clsb:=cls
    urma:=ta.rma(u, period)
    drma:=ta.rma(d,period)
else
    clst:=na
    clsb:=clsb[1]
    u:=na
    d:=na
    urma:=urma[1]
    drma:=drma[1]


rs = ((urma*(period-1)+math.max(close - clsb, 0))/(period+1)) / ((drma*(period-1)+math.max(clsb-close, 0))/(period+1))
rsilive = 100 - 100 / (1 + rs)



plot(rsilive)
```